# convert from 'int?' to '<anonymous type: int pkg_ID>'

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error:

> I cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is the code:

```
NoOfSales = vehicle.Sales.Count == 0 ? 0 : vehicle.Sales.Sum(s => s.NoOfSales)
```

Comment: Look into the `HasValue` and `Value` properties of Nullable types.

Comment: Right, the compiler is telling you what you can do... do you understand the error message? (In fact, there's a better approach here, which is to *always* use `Sum`.)

Comment: So, read the message and do it.. CAST!

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, read the message, and try to understand it. Casting can only be the right solution if you know that the result will never be `null`.

Answer (score 3):

just do,

```
NoOfSales = vehicle.Sales.Sum(s => s.NoOfSales) ?? 0;
```

The [`Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable<Nullable<Int32>>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of `Sum` ignores `null` values. However, if all the values in the sequence are null it must return a `null`.

Comment: You don't need the null coalesce operator.  Sum will treat nulls as 0.

Comment: @juharr, you are correct http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: again its showing this error...The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: My full code is                                                        public ActionResult Report()
        {
            var context = new SalesDatabaseEntities();
            var data = from vehicle in context.VehicleTables
                       select new ReportInfo
                       {
                           Model = vehicle.Model,
                           NoOfSales = vehicle.Sales.Count == 0 ? 0 : vehicle.Sales.Sum(s => s.NoOfSales)
                       };
            ViewBag.Reports = data.ToList();
            return View();
        }

Comment: @NayanAgrawal what type is `NoOfSales` ?

Comment: plz correct this i have tested it using.... NoOfSales = vehicle.Sales.Sum(s => s.NoOfSales); also.....

Comment: Icollection <Sale> VehicleTable.Sales

Comment: @NayanAgrawal You might need `NoOfSales = vehicle.Sales.Sum(s=>s.NoOfSales).Value;` if `ReportInfo.NoOfSales` is of type `int`.

Comment: let me see   @juharr

Comment: again its showing error.................The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: its all done by me .....NoOfSales =vehicle.Sales.Count==0?0:(vehicle.Sales.Sum(s=>s.NoOfSales)).Value......is working fine.....thanks all for ur suggestions

Comment: @NayanAgrawal you don't need the `Count` check. Your solution would fail with a 1 or more null values.